# How do I send something to connected websocket clients from another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I am writing a Python 3.5 program which handles some signals and serves this data to a small amount of  websocket clients.
I want the websocket server and the signal handling to happen in the same program, therefore I am using threading.

The problem is I don't know how to send data from the worker thread to the client.

The Websocket server is implemented with a simple library called "websockets". The server is set up and clients can connect and talk to the server within the "new websocket client has connected" handler.

The server is set up with the help of an event loop:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(newWsHandler, host, port)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
loop.run_forever()
```

Because I want my program to do signal handling too, and loop.run_forever() is a blocking call, I create an endless worker thread before I start my server. This works as expected.

When the worker thread detects a signal change, it has to alert the connected websocket clients. But a simple client.send() does not work. Putting await in front of it does not work either (since that only works within coroutines, I think). I tried making a separate "async def" function and adding it to the event loop, but it gets a bit complicated because it's not on the same thread.

So the main question is: what is the best way send something to a websocket client from a worker thread? I don't receive anything in response.

EDIT:
It will probably help if I add some mock code.

```
def signalHandler():
    #check signals
    ...
    if alert:
        connections[0].send("Alert") #NEED HELP HERE

async def newWsHandler(websocket, path):
    connections.append(websocket)

    while True:
        #keep  the connection open until the client disconnects
        msg = await websocket.recv()

#top level
connections = []
...
start_server = websockets.serve(newWsHandler, host, port)

signalThread = Thread(target = signalHandler)
signalThread.setDaemon(True)
signalThread.start()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)

loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I ended up not using threads. I changed my signal handler code to be an asyncio coroutine and added it to the event loop.

Comment: Can you please share that code

Comment: I guess it was something along these lines: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#both.